# Access token getting 401 from Adal.JS for Azure Data Catalog

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, adal.js, azure-data-catalog

I am building an angular web application using ADAL.js that accesses other Azure APIs and I am successful in accessing custom web API, Power BI API, and the Graph API. Unfortunately I am unable to access the Azure Data Catalog, I am acquiring the token like all the other services by requesting by resource URI. I have added the users and the app service principal name as Catalog Users and the app registration has Azure Data Catalog delegated access. Below is the code that I use to get the token and then I attach it to the header like I do for the other APIs. This is the only Azure API I have had problems accessing. Thanks in advance if anyone is able to help.

```js
var token = authContext.acquireToken('https://api.azuredatacatalog.com')
```

Comment: Which api you cannot call?

Comment: I been trying the search API from Azure Data Catalog following these instructions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datacatalog/data-catalog-data-asset#search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the Azure Data Catalog rest api with adad.js, please refer to the following steps

1. Register an Azure AD application
2. Configure permissions
   [image]
3. Code

```
var resource ="https://api.azuredatacatalog.com"
authContext.acquireToken(resource, function (error, token) {

            // Handle ADAL Error
            if (error || !token) {
                printErrorMessage('ADAL Error Occurred: ' + error);
                return;
            }

            // Get TodoList Data
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://api.azuredatacatalog.com/catalogs/{catalog_name}/search/search?api-version={api-version}&searchTerms={search_terms}",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                },
            });
```